# What is this white, 6 petaled, spike flower?

Tags: identification, flowers, bulbs

I found this while hiking a trail passing through an old homestead near Hillsborough, NC. It was abundant in a wooded area.  It blooms in April. It is about ten inches tall with a spike flower, grassy leaves and the flower is about 1.5 -2 inches in diameter. It is not native to North Carolina and is probably a bulb. 
 [image]

Comment: I'm not in North American flora, but for me it could be one Asphodelus or Ornithogalum

Comment: Giacomo got it in one: It's ornithogalum nutans:  shttps://comptonverneylandscapegarden.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/compton-verney-spring-flowers-2014-29.jpg